# How to write Linq (or lambda) statement to produce all element that are NOT IN (or NOT EXIST)

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda, not-exists

Here is my scenario (Tables):

```
Orders
======================
Id (int)  
description (varchar)

Products
======================
Id (int)
description (varchar)

OrderProductXREF (cross reference table)
======================
ProductId (int)
OrderId (int)
```

I think you get an idea. Nothing unusual is here.

When imported to EDMX file **OrderProductXREF** table is not visible entity. All I see is navigational properties: **Products** for entity **Order** and **Orders** for entity **Product**.

So, my problem:
**I need Linq and/or Lambda statement that will list all Products that don't have any Orders associated with. Or, list all Products that are never ordered.**

SQL would go like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Products
WHERE Id NOT IN 
   (SELECT ProductId 
    FROM OrderProductXREF)
```

**EDIT:**
Uh... sorry forgot one little detail in my question.

Here is the new SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Products
WHERE Id NOT IN 
   (SELECT ProductId 
    FROM OrderProductXREF
    WHERE OrderID = 1)
```

In words, All Products that are NOT ORDERED in order with ID = 1

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies - misread the question beforehand. I suspect you want:

```
var query = db.Products.Where(product => !product.Orders.Any());
```

You should definitely check the generated SQL though. I would *expect* it to be sensible, but if it's not, you would probably want to look at other alternatives.

EDIT: To check products not in order ID 1, you could probably use:

```
var query = db.Products.Except(db.Orders
                                 .Where(order => order.Id == 1)
                                 .Single()
                                 .Products);
```

Or:

```
var query = db.Products.Where(product => !product.Orders
                                                 .Where(order => order.Id == 1)
                                                 .Any());
```

Comment: @CraigStuntz: I'd already edited before your comment and before I saw your answer :) (I realize our answers are very similar, but I've kept mine as an alternative as I believe the method notation is cleaner here - the query expression just adds noise. And also for the suggestion of checking the generated SQL.)

Comment: `Any()` is translated (by the SQL Server provider, anyway) as `EXISTS`, which will produce a reasonable execution plan.

Comment: @CraigStuntz: That's what I'd hope, certainly. I'd probably still check though :)

Comment: Thank you guys. Please see my edit above. Forgot one little detail.
What if I want to list products that are not ordered in order with ID=1? While I was composing my question, I forgot this detail.

Comment: hm. I couldn't make it work. For Linq, it was complaining about last line "...Products());". I replaced it with "...Products);". But still it wouldn't work. Lambda statement always returns empty result.

Comment: @bobetko: Not sure why I had that `Products()` call. Very odd. Try the edited version. Both *should* work though, so long as you have some products which aren't part of order 1...

Comment: First statement can't pass validation. I Get following error: Can't convert Order to System.Collections.Generic.IENumerable<Product>. What I read about Except says that it has to be used something like <Product>.Except<Product> and in your case it is <Product>.Except<Order>. I think I will try some "manual" way to get result I need.

Comment: @bobetko: Okay, I now know what I was thinking - it should have been the Products property, not a Products() method call. Try it now :)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I'll mark your answer as correct one. Second statement works fine. One with "Except" doesn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
var q = from p in Context.Products
        where !p.Orders.Any()
        select p;
```

Regarding your "one little detail":

```
var q = from p in Context.Products
        where !p.Orders.Any(o => o.Id == 1)
        select p;
```

Comment: Thanks. This is useful. Please see my edit above. Forgot one little detail. What if I want to list products that are not ordered in order with ID=1?